# How to explore more defaults write tweaks on OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-mountain-lion

I would like to explore some new tweaks which can be done by the "defaults write" command in OS X(ML).

What can I do to find them out myself rather than hunting online for known tweaks?

Answer (score 23):

**Disclaimer:** I’m the author of [`~/.osx`, a collection of `defaults write` settings](http://mths.be/osx). These are the techniques that I use to find settings. Let me know if there is a better/easier method I didn’t mention here!

---

For most non-hidden settings, this is how you can find the correct preference keys in Terminal.app:

```
defaults read > a
# Change the setting
defaults read > b
diff a b
```

For hidden settings, it gets trickier. You can use the command-line `strings` utility on any binary executable and see if any of the resulting text looks like a preference key. E.g.:

```
strings /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder
```

Here’s another example that will look through all `.framework` files in `/System/Library/Frameworks/` and filter the output somewhat:

```
strings /System/Library/Frameworks/*.framework/Versions/Current/* /System/Library/Frameworks/*/Frameworks/*/Versions/Current/* 2> /dev/null | grep -E '^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{10,80}$' | sort | uniq
```

There’s also a tool called [GDB](http://arcticmac.home.comcast.net/~arcticmac/tutorials/gdbFindingPrefs.html) which can be used to find hidden preferences.

Comment: Thank you very much and I can't believe that you are replying me! I knew about your nice list at github long time ago btw. Thank you very very much! Will try this now.

Comment: @Lri FWIW, I’ve done a clean Mountain Lion install just last week and `defaults read;` works fine here.

Comment: To check the specific type of the fields, use defaults export to check the list! Use the type -float for defaults for the type <real> in the plist

Comment: Adding to this: According to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/414836/130792), you can make `defaults write` take effect without logout-login/restarting with `activateSettings -u`

Answer (score 0):

Another strings command:

`for f in $(mdfind kMDItemContentType==public.unix-executable -onlyin /System/Library/); do strings $f 2> /dev/null | grep -E '^[[:alnum:]_.-]{10,80}$' | grep ^Apple | sort -u | sed "s/^/${f##*/} /g"; done`

`sudo opensnoop -n cfprefsd` shows what property lists are modified. You can use [fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start/) to display other file system changes in real time.

defaults has a find subcommand:

```
$ defaults find nsquitalw
Found 1 keys in domain 'Apple Global Domain': {
    NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows = 1;
}
```

Header files often contain definitions for preference keys:

```
grep PreferenceKey -r ~/Code/Source/WebKit/ | grep '\.h:'
```

Answer (score -1):

What i assumed from your question is you want to explore tweaks/settings of an application. You can read preferences of an app with this trivial command

`defaults read NSGlobalDomain`

or

`defaults read com.google.Chrome` to read chrome writeable preferences from defaults write command which you asked for.