# Changing OS X keyboard type via command-line

Tags: osx-lion, keyboard-layout, osx-mountain-lion, system-preferences

I have a Mac and using it with an external keyboard.

I know that whenever you connect a new keyboard, OS X asks you to detect a keyboard layout by pushing a few keys, and very same thing can be done via Apple Menu > System Preferences > Keyboard > Change Keyboard Type... button.

Somehow my OS X forgets the layout settings whenever it reboots, and asks me to set the layout again. Also, I would like it to stick with one layout for whatever keyboard it gets.

Is there any simple way to achieve this? I am feeling that there should be either:

- A console command to do the same thing that UI does, or
- An underlying function call to either the kernel or some driver, which the Keyboard.prefPane uses.

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: See [here](http://superuser.com/q/301305/156043).

Comment: I don't even have that button, but you might see what key is changed [by diffing the output of defaults read](http://superuser.com/questions/455755/how-to-explore-more-defaults-write-tweaks-on-os-x).

Comment: @Lri *Change Keyboard Type…* requires a non-Apple keyboard, IIRC, I had that button with my Das Keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING: I experienced some macOS crashes after doing what is described below. Pressing any key on the external keyboard crashed my MacBook. I recovered by (sudo) deleting `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist`.**

While you might need to logout/reboot for this to have any effect, you can write a value to the entry corresponding to your keyboard in `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist` using [defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13746408/438249). I believe a value of 41 represents ISO.

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist keyboardtype -dict-add "49948-1133-0" 41
```

Find out which dictionary key you need to change by finding the vendor and product IDs for your keyboard:

```
ioreg -p IOUSB -c IOUSBDevice | grep -e class -e idVendor -e idProduct
```

P.S. I noticed the *Change Keyboard Type* button doesn't always appear. Sometimes it will after re-plugging the keyboard, sometimes it won't. And even then changing the type won't have any effect.